# Saving Fractions in C

Tags: c, root, fractions

so I am quite a beginner here in C and I am constructing a program that will find the roots of polynomial. I am tasked to print out the roots in fractions and whole number. But I really have no idea how to do it. I tried float but basically its for decimals, while the int doesn't print out anything other than the whole numbers. I hope you can help me.

I included the code I have written so far.

```
int last;
    int n=0;
    int lastfactor_arr[20];
    for(last=1; last<=input[token_counter-1]; last++)
    {
        if(input[token_counter-1]%last == 0)
            {
            lastfactor_arr[n] = last;
            printf("factors are: %d\n", lastfactor_arr[n]);
            n++;
            lastfactor_arr[n] = last * -1;
            printf("last factors are: %d\n", lastfactor_arr[n]);
            n++;
            }       
    }
    printf("Total number of factors are: %d\n", n);

    int roots_arr[20];
    int answer;
    int root;
    int k, j, f=0;
    int s_root;
    int nume, deno;

    for(k=0; k<=m-1; k++) //LOOP FOR FIRST FACTOR
    {
        for(j=0; j<=n-1; j++) //LOOP FOR LAST FACTOR
        {
        answer = firstfactor_arr[k]/lastfactor_arr[j];
        if(answer==0)
            {
        nume = firstfactor_arr[k];
        deno = lastfactor_arr[j];
        s_root = (input[token_counter-1]*(nume/deno*nume/deno)) + (input[token_counter-2]*nume/deno) + input[0];
            if(s_root == 0)
                {
            roots_arr[f] = nume/deno;
            f++;
                }
            }
        else
            {   
        root = (input[token_counter-1]*(answer*answer)) + (input[token_counter-2]*answer) + input[0];
            if(root == 0)
                {
            roots_arr[f] = answer;
            f++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int p;
    printf("The rational roots of the input polynomial are: ");
    for(p=0; p<=f; p++)
    {
    printf("%.d,", roots_arr[p]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want either `div_t` or `ldiv_t` in `<stdlib.h>`.  See the documentation of the `div()` standard library function.  You can call this to get the quotient and remainder of your division with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  static const int n = 10, d = 7;
  const div_t result = div(n, d);
  const double x = n/(double)d;

  printf("%f = %d %d/%d\n",
         x, result.quot, result.rem, d);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

An alternative is to replace `result.quot` with `n/d` and `result.rem` with `n%d`.  This lets you take out the line declaring `result`, which you no longer need.

Comment: The functions might well be helpful, but they're not essential (there's a `%` and a `/` operator that also work).   But you've not done very much explanation of how they might be used.

Comment: Those might not work exactly as expected for negative numbers.

Comment: As an FYI, I checked all combinations of ±243 and ±42 with both `div()` and `/` and `%`, and I got the same result for each inputs with the function and the operators (±5 and ±33).  This was compiling with GCC 5.2.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.5, and also with clang (Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)) from XCode 7.  I think that's required by C99 and C11; things may have changed compared with C89/C90.

Comment: Ah.  Yes, that became mandatory in C99 and C++03.  So the OP could replace `result.quot` with `n/d` and `result.rem` with `n%d` in my example.